# How do I retroactively add a primary key to my table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, primary-key, key

I've created a table without a primary key (:id => false), but now it has come back to bite my ass.

My app is already in production and I can't just drop it and recreate another one.

Is there a way to run a migration to add another auto increment primary key column to my table?

Comment: which DB engine are you using?

Comment: Be sure to test any changes you make on a test system, not on production!

Comment: sqlite in development, but PostgreSQL in production

Comment: It can be tough to properly test certain things to make sure they'll work in production when you're using a different development database.  I've always advocated using the same kind of database in dev. so you can be sure everything will work the same.

Comment: You should choose the right answer as accepted

Answer (score 67):

The command to add a primary key in a migration is:

`add_column :my_table, :id, :primary_key`

However, the wording of your question suggests that your table already has an auto-increment column.  Unless I'm mistaken, there are several DBMS that do not allow more than one auto-increment column on a table.

If you DO already have an auto-increment column and you actually want to use that column as your primary key, just add the following to your model:

`set_primary_key "my_existing_column"`

Or in more recent versions of Rails:

`self.primary_key = "my_existing_column"`

In the case that you already have an auto-increment column and you can't use that as the primary key, you may be out of luck.

Comment: Looks like set_primary_key doesn't exist anymore https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/issues/83

Comment: This is a better answer.

Answer (score 14):

If for some reason you created a table with a custom `id` field, but forgot to set `id` as the primary key, you need to run a migration to create the primary key constraint. The following was tested against a PostgreSQL database:

```
class AddPrimaryKeyConstraintToFoobars < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER TABLE foobars ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);"
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER TABLE foobars DROP CONSTRAINT foobars_pkey;"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I know in mySQl that you can add a column that has a default increment value.
If you add that then each row will have a unique int value (and any new row will get a int value 1 greater then the last row added)

You could add this column and set it as a primary key.

Comment: is there a rails way of doing it?

Comment: Or will the SQL statement work for both sqlite and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Was this a join table that now needs to become a real model with a primary key?  If so, your best bet is to create the new table and copy the data into it.

Comment: What would be the best way to transfer the data over to a new table?