# Create a primary key for a table without one in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration, primary-key

I've created table

```
create_table :friendships , :force => true, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :person_id
  t.integer :friend_id
end
```

Now i need to create id for that table. how can i do that in migration?

Comment: minute after i've asked i found an answer  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328528/how-do-i-retroactively-add-a-primary-key-to-my-table-in-rails

Comment: so please post your answer as an answer of your question and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The command to add a primary key in a migration is:

```
add_column :my_table, :id, :primary_key
```